# Android - Allow text highlighting without triggering CAB

Tags: android

I'm trying to figure out how to allow text highlighting inside an EditText, without triggering the Contextual Action Bar.

I've seen it's possible to set a custom Actionmode.Callback that's stops the CAB showing, but from what i can tell it stops the text highlighting as well.

It's definitely possible as it's done in the current Google Docs app, they show a custom popup when text is highlighted instead of the CAB.

Comment: Take a look at ActionBarSherlock, how Jake work around it